# list of branches sorting

Tags: python, list, tree, list-comprehension

I have a tree network in which I want to find the 'generation' of all the parent nodes (see below).

[image: Image indicating horizontal tree i.e. a network]

All parent nodes have exactly two children.

This is presented in the lists as:

```
parents  = [   2,     3,           1,       5,        4,          7,          8,          9,         6,        10     ]
children = [ [4,5],  [0,11],     [6,10]   [1,7]     [8,9]      [12,13],    [14,15],    [16,17],   [18,19],   [20,21]  ]
```

So for example the parent node '2' has immediate children nodes [4,5].

I define the generation of a parent as the longest route to a node with no children. So for example with parent node '2' there are many different routes to a node with no children e.g.

1)  2 --> 4 --> 9 --> 17

2)  2 --> 5 --> 1 --> 10 --> 21

Since the second route is the longer route, generation of parent '2' is 4 as it takes 4 nodes to reach to '21' and '21'is a leaf node.

So with the `parents` list in this case my desired result would be:

```
generation = [4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

where each index of the `generation` list corresponds to the generation of the node in the `parents` list.

How do I get the generation list from the `parents` and `children` list?

Comment: Try writing a program to accomplish this; come back when you have specific problem(s).

Comment: Your picture is sideways.

Comment: look at Python modules/libraries implementing "graphs". For example: https://networkx.github.io/documentation.html

Comment: Hi @MaxU I have used networkx before but I can't use it for other reasons. I'm interested in a solution that tackles it with list gymnastics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one-line solution, not too performant though:

```
parents  = [   2,     3,           1,       5,        4,          7,          8,          9,         6,        10     ]
children = [ [4,5],  [0,11],     [6,10],  [1,7],    [8,9],     [12,13],    [14,15],    [16,17],   [18,19],   [20,21]  ]

generation=[(lambda f,*x:f(f,*x))(lambda g,i,c:max(g(g,j,c)+1for j in c[i])if i in c else 0,i,dict(zip(parents,children)))for i in parents]

print(generation)
```

PS: The parents and children array definitions you provided were missing some commas.

**UPDATE**

Here is the performant version, featuring memoized recursion:

```
parents  = [   2,     3,           1,       5,        4,          7,          8,          9,         6,        10     ]
children = [ [4,5],  [0,11],     [6,10],  [1,7],    [8,9],     [12,13],    [14,15],    [16,17],   [18,19],   [20,21]  ]

generation=(lambda c:list(map((lambda f,m={}:lambda x:m[x]if x in m else m.setdefault(x,f(f,x)))(lambda g,i:max(g(g,j)+1for j in c[i])if i in c else 0),parents)))(dict(zip(parents,children)))

print(generation)
```

Comment: Thanks Tamas. What's the purpose behind `repr`. I find that if I remove `repr` I still get the correct list

Comment: @user2443944 nothing, you can leave that.

Answer (score 1):

While there is a concise solution that calculates the generation of each node, you could also implement a tree data structure that tracks the generation of each node.

```
class Forest:
    def __init__(self, forest_dict):
        self.trees = [Tree(value, children) for value, children in forest_dict.items()]

    def __iter__(self):
        for tree in self.trees:
            for node in iter(tree):
                yield node

class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, children):
        self.root = node = Node(value)
        self.__recurse(node, children)

    def __recurse(self, node, children):
        for value, subchildren in children.items():
            child = Node(value, node)
            node.addChild(child)
            self.__recurse(child, subchildren)

    def __iter__(self):
        for node in iter(self.root):
            yield node

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, parent=None):
        self.value = value
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []
        self.generation = 0

    def addChild(self, child):
        if not self.children:
            node, generation = self, 1
            while node is not None:
                node.generation = max(node.generation, generation)
                generation += 1
                node = node.parent

        self.children.append(child)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self
        for child in self.children:
            for subchild in iter(child):
                yield subchild
```

Then, if you structure your forestas a nested dictionary, it's easy to get a list of the parent node generations'.

```
forest_dict =   {2: 
                    {4: 
                        {8: 
                            {14: {}, 
                             15: {}
                            }, 
                         9: {16: {}, 
                             17: {}
                            }
                        }, 
                     5: 
                        {1: 
                            {6: 
                                {18: {}, 
                                 19: {}
                                }, 
                            10: 
                                {20: {}, 
                                 21: {}
                                }
                            },
                         7:
                            {12: {},
                             13: {}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                3: 
                    {0: {},
                     11: {}
                    }
                }

forest = Forest(forest_dict)
print [node.generation for node in forest if node.generation]
# [4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Obviously, this is a lot more work, but might be worth it depending on what you're doing. Note that the order isn't exactly the same since dictionaries and different structures.